# Entity Framework: Mapping to Custom Method for Timezone support

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're looking into switching our current hand-written ORM to Entity Framework. We have support in our program to take the UTC datetime in the DB to display to the USER as their preferred timezone. Our methods are as follows

Utilities.CovertToUserTimeZone(DbValue); for going from the db to the user

and

Utilities.ConvertToUtcTimeZone(property); for going from the user to the db

How can I edit the Mapping.tt file in EntityFramework to add this to any DateTime property. I was able to add this to the Entity.tt but then I realized I have to do it in the Mapping.tt file and not Entity.tt, and I don't see how that would work with the ".hascolumnname("column") that I can map that value through a method before applying it through the property. any ideas

Comment: Well, you don't have to make it inside EF. Probably you can recycle your old code and make it an extended method to DateTime?

Comment: How would that work to apply to all mapped datetime properties?

Comment: Consider to create an domain entity to wrap around your model. The getter of your DateTime property should return _dateTime.ToLocalTimeZone(), presumably you extended method is named ToLocalTimeZone().